# C++ outputting weird

Tags: c++, output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
  cout << "*****************************************" <<
    endl <<
    cout << "Hello All!" <<
    endl <<
    cout << "Welcome to CSCI-111!!!!!" <<
    endl <<
    cout << "It is great to see you!" <<
    endl <<
    cout << "*****************************************" ;

  return 0;

}
```

The first cout is fine and outputs correctly, but every cout after that outputs a strange string of numbers before the words in quotation marks (0x600e88) and my output ends up looking like this

```
***************************************** 
0x600e88Hello All! 
0x600e88Welcome to CSCI-111!!!!! 
0x600e88It is great to see you! 
0x600e88*****************************************
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl

Comment: What `cout << cout ?` will result in ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you currently have:

```
cout << "blah" << endl << cout << "blah" << endl << cout << ... ;
//                        ^~~~                      ^~~~
```

You're printing the `cout` itself, this is what gives you weird numbers.

What you should have:

```
cout << "blah" << endl;
cout << "blah" << endl;
```

Or:

```
cout << "blah" << endl
     << "blah" << endl;
```

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Terminate `endl`s:

```
cout << "*****************************************" << endl;
cout << "Hello All!" << endl;
cout << "Welcome to CSCI-111!!!!!" << endl;
cout << "It is great to see you!" << endl;
cout << "*****************************************" ;
```

Or delete the redundant `cout`s:

```
cout << "*****************************************" << endl <<
    "Hello All!" << endl <<
    "Welcome to CSCI-111!!!!!" << endl <<
    "It is great to see you!" << endl <<
    "*****************************************" ;
```

Otherwise, the expression continues, and you print `cout` itself, and since it's a function pointer, you print it's address (`0x600e88`).

---

In the sequence

```
cout << "Something" << endl << cout;
```

the first `cout` indicates the start of `ostream` (a stream printing *out* to the console), while the second one is the part of the stream you want to output, and is treated as a pointer, who outputs what he contains - a numeric address of the call to `cout`.

Comment: Wait, since when `cout` is a function pointer? It wouldn't be possible to print builtin types with it if it were a pointer.

Comment: It may also be a good idea not to use `endl` every line because it isn't needed.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: It decays to a boolean expression. One common way to do that is `ostream* operator() const {return good()?this:nullptr;}` (this isn't a function pointer, no idea why Uriel wrote that)

Comment: @juanchopanza you can replace it by `\n`, but I intend to keep OP original code as matching

Comment: @MooingDuck My point is that the `cout` itself is *not* a pointer.

Comment: Ah. I see I see thanks for the clarification !